# How to insert list of records using LWC? Error : Too many DML Statement 1

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, insert

Apex :

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static void createFilters(List<Criteria__c> criteres ) {
    List<Criteria__c> crit = new List<Criteria__c>();
    for(Criteria__c cr : Criteres){
      crit.add(cr);
    }
    upsert crit;
  }
```

JS :

```
 createFilter(){
        const modifiedFilters = this.caseDefaultData
         .filter(
          (row) =>
            (!row.Id) || // This is a new row not from the database
           Object.entries(row).some(
              ([field, value]) => field !== 'index' && field !== 'rowNumber' && this.originalData.find((data)=>data.Id===row.Id)[field] !== value
            )
        )
        .map((row, index) => ({
          Id: row.Id,
          ...Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(row).filter(
               // Find fields that have been modified
               ([field, value]) => field !== 'index' && field !== 'rowNumber' && (!row.Id || this.originalData.find((data)=>data.Id===row.Id)[field] !== value)
            )
           ),
         }));
         createCriterias({criteres :  modifiedFilters}).then(result => {
         })
    }
```

**modifiedFilters** contains only the values who has been changed or values which has been created in UI so that's why i used *upsert*  , Result :

[image]

Comment: When are you calling this `createCriterias` function in the component's lifecycle? The error message you're asking about ("Too many DML Statements: 1") means that you are attempting to do a DML (insert, update, upsert, delete) operation at a time where it is not allowed. Are you calling this function in `connectedCallback` or `init`?

Comment: in @wire , i have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The error is being caused by your usage of `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` on the `createCriterias` function definition.

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm)

> To improve runtime performance, set @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) to cache the method results on the client. To set cacheable=true, a method must only get data. It can’t mutate data.

Removing the `cacheable=true` from the `@AuraEnabled` annotation should sort out your issue.