# Too many DML statements: 1 LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, dmlexception

Hello everybody I am working on a LWC form that gather information from the user and validates it and create a new record with the data in the form. The problem is that I am getting a **Too many DML statements: 1**

.js is the next one where the handleValidacion is the event that triggers when the user validates it and the wrapperC101 is the apex method:

```
handleValidacion(event){
    console.log('inside button handler');
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element =>{
        element.reportValidity();
    })
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox').forEach(element =>{
        element.reportValidity();
    })
    console.log('whats inside the wrapper...'+ JSON.stringify(this.createWrapper()) );
    wrapperC101({wrapperWithInfo : JSON.stringify(this.createWrapper()),recordIdAccount: '$recordId' }).then((result) =>{
        const{data,error} = result;
        this.data = result;
        console.log('data from apex function...'+ this.data);
        for (var iMessage of this.data){
            const notificationError = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: iMessage,
                variant: 'error'
            });
```

in my apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled/*(cacheable=true)*/
public static List<String> getInformationFromLWC(String wrapperWithInfo, Id recordIdUser){
    
    
    WrapperInterface newWrapper = newInstance.createWrapper(wrapperWithInfo);
    
    if(something true){
        createRecord(newWrapper,recordIdUser );
        return null;
    }else{
    ....
    }
}
public static void createRecord(QX_WrapperInterface newWrapper, Id recordIdUser){
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name = 'Vi';
    insert a;
}
```

I am getting the error in the 'insert a'; could anybody help me?
I have read that removing the (cacheable=true) it worked but it is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too many DML Statements: 1 when upserting records from LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/384861/too-many-dml-statements-1-when-upserting-records-from-lwc)

Comment: @PhilW hello I already tried it but is still with the same problem.

Comment: Watch out also for how you pass parameters to imperative apex; do not try to use wire service reactive parameter syntax.

Comment: Are you sure it was the same problem? I suggest not, but a different error.

Comment: @JaimeGonzalez can you explicitly set cacheable = false and try?